# Catan longest road card question

Tags: catan

After you get the longest road card, can you start building on it and still retain the longest road card?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who would get the longest road?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/who-would-get-the-longest-road)

Comment: I don't think the linked question is at all a duplicate; this isn't asking about the possibility of breaking roads at all.

Comment: I’d love for any of the close voters to explain how this can be considered a duplicate. The linked question is about what happens when the longest road is broken up by a settlement in the middle. This is asking if you can make a longest road even longer by building more. The fact that both questions can be answers by quoting rules that deal with the longest road does not make it a duplicate at all...

Comment: @GendoIkari I originally read this as about building more roads, but my current best guess is that the question is actually about whether your own settlements break up your road. Perhaps this should be closed for clarity until OP clarifies?

Comment: I’m not seeing anything that could be taken as an implication that settlements or breaking up roads could have anything to do with the question.... it sounds to me like the OP thought that once you claimed longest road with “5” length road; that maybe your longest road was stuck at “5” specifically.

Comment: Ok I get it now. The question is if “building on it” means building settlements or roads. I see the ambiguity now. Either way it’s not a duplicate because the other question is about what happens when longest road is broken up by an opponent’s settlements.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can freely extend the length of your longest road to make it even harder for an opponent to claim the Longest Road bonus from you. The rules talk about how you gain the Longest Road card and how someone else takes it from you; nowhere does it say anything that would imply that ownership of the card prevents you from building roads.

Your own settlements and cities do not disrupt your road in any way, but opponents ones do (see Longest Road in the Almanac, p9).

Comment: I think OP's "building on it" probably means adding settlements but I initially read it as adding more roads; pending clarification by OP I'll just leave this as answering both readings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Once you have the longest road card, the only two ways you can lose it are if another player builds:

1. A longer road (has to be at least longer by 1 road), in which case the card goes to said player.
2. A settlement along your longest road causing it to no longer be the longest road. In this case the card goes to the player with the new longest road. If no other player has a road that satisfies the longest road requirement (5+ roads), then the card goes back to the bank until a player becomes once again eligible.